# Use .htaccess redirect to keep original url but show content of redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want people that visit the URL /this-url.html get to see the Site of /that-url but to keep the url as /this-url.html

I already tried various solutions of stackoverflow but none of them worked for me. I tried to use the [P] flag, the [QSA] flag and no flag at all.

My basic code:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/this-url.html$ /that-url

The redirect always works, but it also changes the URL. I need to keep the URL as /this-url.html

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to consult the most important source of information when you want to learn how to use some tool or utility: the documentation. That is, as typical for OpenSource projects, of *excellent* quality and comes with great examples. You really should start looking into it: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Here is a slightly modifed version that should do what you want:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?that-url$ /this-url.html [END]
```

The main difference: in dynamic configuration files `RewriteRules` operate on *relative* paths, you were trying to match against *absolute* paths, which would only work for rules implemented in the real http server's host configuration. The version I posted works likewise, so it is more robust.

If you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using above rule then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case try using the old `L` flag, it will probably work the same here, though that actually depends on the specific situation you are in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I get a 404 Error when I try your solution. I also tried it with the L flag, but it makes no difference... Do you know why?

Comment: Well, most likely what you actually try to do is the opposit eof what you asked. Just guessing, but that makes more sense anyway. So I changed the answer accordingly.